# Combine regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I need help to combine the following two regular expressions:

```
1.ValidationExpression="[^\s]{5,12}" : (5-12 non-blank characters)
2.ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$"    : (Only integers)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples on what the string is that your trying to match and what the result should be?

Comment: When a user is typing I would like to force 5-12 characters while those characters must be integer.

Answer (score 4):

You could only allow 5-12 numbers like this:

```
ValidationExpression="^\d{5,12}$"
```

\d stands for [0-9]

Comment: Do I need to use two different expressions?

Comment: @Eyal: No, this regex alone is sufficient. After all, a digit is a non-blank character.

Answer (score 1):

I fear I might be missing something but won't this do it

```
^[0-9]{5,12}$
```